# Cadastrar Data no MySQL usando Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou tentando cadastrar um campo de data para um sistema de cadastro de serviços e as consultas não estão sendo enviadas para o banco de dados. Tentei usando só o PHP e deu certo, porém quando uso o mesmo código com AJAX não funciona.

Vale lembrar que no meu Banco de Dados, o campo está com o tipo DATE.

Esse é meu PHP (queries.php):

```
if($ordem == 8){
$data = $_POST['date'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO datetest (data)
VALUES ('$data');";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
echo "Data: " .$data. " foi cadastrado com sucesso, com a ID: ". $last_id;
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}}
```

No meu HTML tenho o campo de data:

```
    <label>Data do Serviço</label>
    <input class='form-control' type="date" id='date'>
```

E usando o Ajax para a consulta:

```
function FormSubmit(){
ordem = 8;
date = document.getElementById('date').value;
console.log(date);
$.ajax({
                url:'../config/queries.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    ordem:ordem,
                    date:date
                },
               success:function(data){
                   alert(data);
               }
            });
```

Esse é meu HTML completo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/vendas.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9b1c918fe2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="anime.min.js"></script>
    <title>Cadastro de Clientes</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class='container-fluid' id='bannertop'>
    <h2><i class="fab fa-amazon"></i></h2>
</div>

<div class='row'>
<div class='container-fluid' id='content'>

<div class='row'>


<div class='col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12' id='sidemenu'>

<?php

include_once('../phpmenu.php');

echo $menu;

?>

</div>

<div class='col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-9' id='contentbox'>

    <div class='container-fluid' id='workbox'>
    <div class='row'>

    <div class='col-lg-12 col-xs-12'>
    <h4 style='text-align: center;'>Gerar Ordem de Serviço</h4>


    <div class='row'>

        <div class='container-fluid' id='generateorder'>
        <br>
        <label style='text-align: left;'>Tipo de Serviço</label>
        <select class='form-control' id='servicetype'>
            <option value="1">Dedetização</option>
            <option value="1">Estofado</option>
        </select>

        <label>Cliente</label>
        <select class='form-control' id='cliselect'>
            <option value="">Marcos Alexandria de Oliveira</option>
        </select>

        <label style='text-align: left;'>Produto a utilizar</label>
        <select class='form-control' id='servicetype'>
        <option value="1">Exemplo de Produto</option>
        <option value="1">Estofado</option>
        </select>

        <p></p>
        <label class='form-control' style='background-color: #ced4da;'>Infos do Produto</label>
        <p></p>
        <button class='form-control' id='btnadd'>Adicionar esse produto</button>

        <label>Valor do Serviço</label>
        <input class='form-control' type="text">

        <label>Data do Serviço</label>
        <input class='form-control' type="date" id='date'>

        <label style='text-align: left;'>Funcionário responsável</label>
        <select class='form-control' id='servicetype'>
            <option value="1">Definir mais tarde</option>
            <option value="1">Luis Carlos</option>
            <option value="1">Marcos Alexandria</option>
        </select>

        <br>

        <input class='form-control' value='Cadastrar' onclick='FormSubmit()' type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn">
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>



    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='errors' id='errors'></div>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    ClientList();
});

function ClientList(){
    ordem = 12;
    $.ajax({
                    url:'../config/queries.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        ordem:ordem
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       //alert(data);
                       $("#cliselect").html(data);
                   }
                });
}

function FormSubmit(){
    ordem = 8;
    date = document.getElementById('date').value;
    console.log(date);
    $.ajax({
                    url:'../config/queries.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        ordem:ordem,
                        date:date
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       alert(data);
                   }
                });
}
</script>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: posta o seu html completo e explica o que acontece quando vc tenta submeter seu form

Comment: Dei uma editada e adicionei meu HTML completo cara. Quando dou submit aparece um alert que está ali no código do AJAX mas esse alert não retorna nada, vem vazio. Já tentei colocar o retorno pra uma div e usando console.log(), mas ambas as tentativas também retornam nada, literalmente, se quer um valor NULL ou Undefined.

Comment: o servidor não ta dando erro ou no seu console do navegador?

Comment: 0 erros cara. De inicio eu tava vendo um erro na Sintaxe do MYSQL, quando estava usando com PHP sem AJAX. Corrigi e deu certo. Usando esse mesmo código sem o AJAX está funcionando.

O console.log() da data retorna um valor reconhecido pelo PHP, que já testei também. Ex: 2020-03-25

Comment: Dei uma geral geral mesmo no código e achei o problema. Dentro do queries.php existem vários If's e acidentalmente coloquei esse if dentro das chaves de outro if. Agora está funcionando. Peço desculpas pela falta de atenção mas deixo esse report apenas pro caso de outro usuário ter algum problema parecido.